# Concatenating tr commands in shell

Tags: bash, pipe, tr

I am trying to write a simple shell script to apply letter replacements to a string, and I am unable to apply several in a row.

The following is the simplest example that I cannot get to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
tr a b |  tr b c
```

Now, if I run this script and enter 'a', there is no output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pipe won't flow until end of data is detected.  Try typing 'a' [enter] ctrl-D or use the following:

```
echo a | tr a b | tr b c
```

Comment: or `cat - | tr ...` will process a line-at-a-time. Good luck to all.

Comment: +1 as you actually explained what OP needed to do to make it work and congratulations on reaching 10k. `:)`